# Checking page loading time

Tags: javascript

How to check the performance of an application after the page has been loaded in the browser. I mean, when we do any AJAX call after the page has loaded, how do we get the performance of the page after the call? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You'll want to use the network tab in chrome developer tools.

Answer (score 1):

- Right Click on your page (on browser)
- Inspect Element (on chrome just Inspect)
- Open Network Tab
- Load your page and observe the performance

Comment: Or `F12` on Firefox